# ssh into a server without a public IP from a server without a public IP that is hidden behind a server with public IP

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, ip

I have the following setup: I would like to access machine A from machine C, but neither of those have a public IP address. Machine C is, though, in the same network as machine B, which has a public IP access, hence I can access machine C from anywhere by first ssh'ing into machine B and from there ssh into machine C. I don't have root access on machine B, while at both A and C I do. See the following diagram for clarification:

```
machine A          machine B      machine C
no public IP       public IP      no public IP
root access        no root access root access     
how to access?    '---------------------------'
                           same network
                       hence both accessible
```

A dumb solution would be to have machine A regularly sniff a file in machine C (by the 2-step ssh access described above) and whenever a command appears in that file, execute it and write the outputs over ssh somewhere at machine C. I, though, wonder, can ssh somehow "reverse" the connection, so that machine A connects in 2 steps to machine C, and then the connection gets "reversed" so that machine C actually has the remote shell of machine A? And if yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have `machineA` to open an SSH tunnel to `machineB`, with a remote forward option, which would allow you to SSH into `machineA` from `machineB`.

If you have root access on `machineB`, then set the `GatewayPorts` configuration option to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, then issue this command on `machineA`:

```
ssh -N -R 0.0.0.0:2222:127.0.0.1:22 the_public_ip_of_machine_B
```

This will open the port 2222 on `machineB`, and forward any traffic on that port to itself, to port 22. Note that this will listen on all interfaces, the public one included, so you may want to firewall port number 2222 (but probably you have a firewall on `machineB` anyway). While this tunnel is active, you can SSH to `machineB` on port 2222, and this will take you to `machineA`. Since `machineB` and `machineC` are on the same subnet, you can loginto `machineA` from `machineC` in one step.

If you don't have root access on `machineB`, then the process is the same, with the exception of the listening address. If `GatewayPorts` is set to `no` (which is the default), then the first argument (`0.0.0.0`) will simply be ignored, and the listening address will be bound to `127.0.0.1`. In this case, you can still use the command from above, and the forwarding will work the same, but the opened port will not be available from anywhere but from `machineB`. So you must SSH into `machineB`, then SSH to `localhost`, port 2222, which will take you to `machineA`.

However, you might want to consider using something more robust, like a VPN.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it tomorrow, it is quite late in my location already. I will edit my question, I don't have root access on B and would prefer to do as much as possible on C - machine B is just a frontend to connect through and the admin would not be very happy if I was messing up there.